# YA Book With Boxy Wooden Spaceships

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult, space

As I remember I read it about 1964 in English.

In Earth's future.  One type of space ship, presumably only used for low energy trips in space, perhaps in the asteroid belt, consisted of rectangular wooden boxes (with rocket motors & fuel tanks attached) sort of like old fashioned railroad cars.

I don't remember if they were pressurized or if the passengers had to wear space suits.

If I remember correctly the cover was hard and shiny, and possibly might have been mostly green in color.

Comment: When I read the title, I was thinking Bob Shaw's *The Wooden Spaceships* -- the middle book of a trilogy.  Doesn't fit the rest of the question, though, and certainly wasn't YA.

Comment: @Zeiss Ikon -- That was also my first thought when I saw the title, but I agree this isn't the answer to the question.

Answer (score 5):

Poul Anderson's *The Makeshift Rocket* (serialised in *Astounding* as  *A Bicycle Built For Brew*) had something along those lines, though it was kegs of beer rather than trucks. Was the vessel propelled by beer?

Comment: The magazine serial is available at the Internet Archive, [here](https://archive.org/stream/Astounding_v62n03_1958-11_EXciter-LennyS#page/n0/mode/2up) and [here](https://archive.org/stream/Astounding_v62n04_1958-12_EXciter-LennyS#page/n0/mode/2up) (US edition) or [here](https://archive.org/stream/Astounding_British_Ed._v15n02_1959-02#page/n0/mode/2up) and [here](https://archive.org/stream/Astounding_British_Ed._v15n03_1959-03#page/n1/mode/2up) (UK edition).

Comment: Even if it's not the answer it's great to be reminded of this story, one of my childhood favourites.